# How to delete specific character from c string without converting to string?

Tags: c++

I am trying to delete a specific character (:), which occurs twice in my c string, from a c string without converting it to a string.

So far I tried to do the following but it's deleting every character after (:), which is not what I am trying to do. I'm just trying to take out that specific character.

```
// cString = 09:24:46

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cString); i++){
        cString[2] = '\0';
        cString[5] = '\0';
    }
```

```
//current output: 09
//desired output: 092446
```

What should I make cString[2] and cString[5] equal to? I tried putting them equal to NULL but I get the same output and I also tried spaces but I want the output to have no spaces

Comment: `\0`, the null terminator determines where a C-String stops, that's why setting a character to it makes it look like everything after it has vanished, it simply stops reading. What you need to do is shift all the characters after the one you want to delete backwards, overwriting your unwanted char.

Comment: You will have to reallocate a new `char[]` or at least to "shift" all the characters after the deleted one to the left.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert the C-style string to `std::string` to "remove" characters.

You could use the [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  char cString[] = "09:24:46";
  std::cout << cString << "\n";

  // "Remove" the ':' from the C-style string.  
  // pos will point to the beginning of the "removed" elements 
  auto pos = std::remove(cString, cString + strlen(cString), ':');
  
  // overwrite the removed elements with 0 
  while (*pos)
     *pos = '\0';

  std::cout << cString;
}
```

Output:

```
09:24:46
092446
```

Comment: Why not `std::remove(cString, cString + strlen(cString) + 1, ':');` and no overwrite needed.

Answer (score 1):

'\0' in a character array indicates it's ending. It won't print any further characters.

You can shift all the remaining characters one index back and mark the
last character as '\0' (null).

Like so:

```
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
     if(cString[i] == ':'){
         for(int j = i;j < n-1;j++){
               cString[j] = cString[j+1];
         }
         cString[n-1] = '\0';
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Very useful code. However, it only deletes the first (:). I moved the lines outside the inner-most for loop to be outside the outer for loop and deleted the break statement and it now deletes both

Answer (score 0):

```
const size_t n = strlen(cString);
for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
  if (cString[j] != ':')
    cString[i++] = cString[j];
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some more detail to explain what exactly your answer is doing